Vue.js App Deployed on Render Returns “Not Found” for Sub-Pages or Direct URL Access
I have a Vue.js application built with Vue Router and deployed on Render. The app works perfectly when navigating between pages using Vue Router links. However, I encounter an issue when:
1.  Reloading a sub-page (e.g., https://dev.example.com/services/video) or accessing it directly via URL results in a “Not Found” error (both for pages rendered from DB and static ones).
2.  This issue occurs only on the deployed version (Render). Locally, everything works as expected.
Router Configuration
Here’s my router/index.js setup:
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";
import index from "../views/index.vue";
import NotFound from "../views/404.vue";

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: [
    { path: "/", name: "home", component: index },
    { path: "/:catchAll(.*)", name: "NotFound", component: NotFound },
    { path: "/blog", name: "blog", component: () => import("../views/blog.vue") },
    { path: "/blog/:slug", name: "article", component: () => import("../views/article.vue") },
    { path: "/about", name: "about", component: () => import("../views/about.vue") },
    { path: "/services/photo", name: "photo", component: () => import("../views/Photo.vue") },
    { path: "/services/video", name: "video", component: () => import("../views/Video.vue") },
    { path: "/legal", name: "Legal", component: () => import("../views/legal.vue") },
    { path: "/legal/:id", name: "Legal article", component: () => import("../views/legal-article.vue") },
    { path: "/:pathMatch(.*)*", name: "404", component: NotFound },
  ],
  scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
    if (to.hash) {
      return { el: to.hash, behavior: "smooth" };
    } else if (savedPosition) {
      return savedPosition;
    } else {
      return { top: 0 };
    }
  },
});

router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
  const isAuthenticated = localStorage.getItem("user");
  const requiresAuth = to.matched.some((record) => record.meta.requiresAuth);
  if (!isAuthenticated && requiresAuth) {
    next("/");
  } else {
    next();
  }
});

export default router;


What I’ve Tried

Added a catchAll route



in the router configuration to handle undefined routes.
2.  Confirmed that createWebHistory is used for the router to handle browser history correctly.
3.  Attempted to configure a fallback in the Render hosting settings but couldn’t find clear documentation for SPA handling.
4.  Cleaned up the console logs to rule out potential JavaScript errors.
5.  Locally, the app behaves as expected when testing sub-page reloads or direct URL access.
Question
How can I configure my Vue.js app deployed on Render to handle sub-page reloads and direct URL access without throwing a “Not Found” error? Is there something missing in the router setup?
•   Vue Version: 3
•   Router Mode: createWebHistory


web servers by default look to serve an html page within the app file directory matching the URL path.  being an SPA, you only have one html page.  the web server needs to be configured to redirect all paths to serve just index.html.  see Render documentation.  you want to create a redirect for /* to /index.html

Okay that fixed the "not found"but right now when I go to example.com/about and reload it redirects to example.com/index.html (as the rule says) instead of reloading the current page...

My mistake. Try configuring the rule as a "rewrite" instead of a "redirect".

Okay that technically works - the app does not break (propertirs loaded in app.vue such as header, footer and styles are loaded and URL also coresponds), however the app body that dynamicaly changes according to the body does not show anything...
